# Python | My code recognizes the number 100 on the screen via pytesseract as str, but I need to get an int

Tags: python, string, integer, python-tesseract

There is a number in a certain area
For example - 100
It is recognized through pytesseract (pytesseract.image_to_string) as str, but I need an int to pass the result to the calculation formula, because str does not accept
How can this problem be solved?

I tried to find a solution a long time ago, I don’t remember how I changed the code and what results I got, but I still haven’t found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let s be the image_to_string result.

Then the integer you want is: int(s)

Comment: I will try it a bit later today, thanks for answer

Comment: So, today I finally figured out the previous problems and tried your advice. Everything works, thank you very much